# Understanding CPU threads is used by a multithread application

Tags: cpu, numa

Recently, I did some research on how the CPU core is used by a multi-threaded application. I can see what cores each thread is using by using the following command:

For example: ceph-osd is a multi-threaded application

```
for i in $(pgrep ceph-osd); do ps -mo pid,tid,fname,user,psr -p $i;done
```

My CPU has 32 cores and 72 threads, so the ceph-osd will have 72 TID (thread ID):

```
    PID     TID COMMAND  USER     PSR
 336157       - ceph-osd ceph       -
      -  336157 -        ceph       6
      -  336160 -        ceph      51
      -  336162 -        ceph      57
      -  336163 -        ceph      23
      -  336164 -        ceph      22
      -  336168 -        ceph       7
      -  336169 -        ceph      17
      -  336203 -        ceph       1
...
...
```

But what I don't understand is:

- This ceph-osd process will use all the CPU cores, or if the thread is just allocated and maybe not always in use?
- If I use numactl to define affinity and bind the process to specific threads, will it make any different than before?
- There are more than one ceph-osd process on my server, so will it help improve performance when binding manually?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What scheduler ? What scheduling policy for ceph-osd processes ?

Comment: "none" scheduler is in use and scheduling policy of ceph-osd processes is currently SCHED_OTHER. It is default setting

Comment: It is unclear to me whether your question is general or precisely & exclusively targeted to ceph which is one very particular sort of multi-threaded app. Moreover it launches different sort of threads (op threads / disk threads). Not to say that your configuration does not appear the default one since, AFAIK default for max nb of op threads = 2 and default for max nb of disk threads = 1